# Getting error in route parameter in angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm getting error in route in angular4

I've main component named Category, in that category component I've created further two components named category-add.component.ts and category-edit.component.ts

Directory structure:
[image]

Add new category route is working fine. but edit route is not working.

Routes:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule , FormsModule , HttpModule, RouterModule, FlashMessagesModule ,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path : 'category/edit/:id',
        component : CategoryEditComponent
      },
      {
        path : 'category',
        component: CategoryComponent
    },
      {
        path : 'category/add',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: CategoryAddComponent
    },
    {
        path : 'add-user',
        component : AddUserComponent
      },
      {
        path : 'add-member',
        component : AddMemberComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
```

Edit

On link click, I'm getting this error: 
[image: Edit Button clicked Image]
I don't have any provider for the component so what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you injected `CategoryComponent` inside constructor of `class` like below.

```
constructor(private categoryComponent: CategoryComponent) {}
```

You shouldn't be injected Component as Injectable. Create Injectable service and use it as service. Also before using that service declare the same in `providers` metadata option of `AppModule`

Comment: Yeah, you are right that was the issue. Problem Solved. Thanks

Comment: @RizwanSaleem Glad to help you, Thanks :)